# Instead of "sound", can I use "is it" here?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

In *Sweet Smell of Success* (1957), J.J speaks to Senator Harvey about picking a correct press agent:

> J.J: You're a family man, Harvey, and someday, God willing, you may
> want to be president. And here you are, out in the open...where any
> hep person knows that this one... is toting that one around for you.
> Are we kids, or what? Next time you come up, you might  join me on my
> T.V. show.
>
> Senator Harvey: Thanks, J.J., for what I consider **sound** advice.

Instead of "sound", can I use "is it" here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the dictionary for the adjective meaning of "sound".

It means "good or safe and able to be trusted" (Cambridge) and is used particularly to describe "advice".

So you could replace this with "good (advice)".  You can't replace it with "it is"; that would be grammatically wrong and change the meaning.